# Syntax highlight in search result for visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, search, syntax-highlighting

It is hard to read the find result in `mono color`.
Since I search for code very often, I would love to have the search result text to be formatted as the code accordingly to the file type e.g. C# syntax for .cs files

What should we do to have this feature? Y

[image]

Comment: Does this help? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e39a6996-ea46-459a-9f1e-9629547868bc

Comment: Awesome! Please put that as an answer to get accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the extension [Entrian Source Search](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e39a6996-ea46-459a-9f1e-9629547868bc).

Answer (score 1):

[VSColorOutput](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4d9c2b5-d6d7-4543-a7a5-2d7ebabc2496) extension can highlight text in the Output window and the Find Results Window with custom colors according to your selected regex patterns.

Comment: Is it stable now @Sergey Vlasov? I see the review and QnA with lots of issues :(

Comment: I don't use VSColorOutput personally, but looks like it is actively maintained and problems are resolved.